# mysql - adding composite primary key removes index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have issues adding composite primary key to existing table. Adding the pk works, but removing it in down migration fails.

I have users_companies table, connecting users table and companies table. `users_companies` table consists of two columns, userId and companyId, both foreign keys of course. My problem is there is no primary key for this table. When I add a primary key, using `ALTER TABLE users_companies ADD PRIMARY KEY(userId, companyId)`, everything seems to work fine. But, once I try to undo that primary key (for migration rollback) I get following error:

> Error on rename of './db_name/#sql-1_9' to
>   './db_name/users_companies' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint
>   is incorrectly formed)

That means I'm unable to remove the PK for migration rollback.

After a while, I've noticed that adding that primary key removes fk index `users_companies.userId`. Adding that index manually again makes PK dropping work again. Still, that index isn't always removed when creating the primary key (it depends on database I'm using), so I can't simply recreate index after adding PK. If I copy current database with data in it and try to run the migration, index is not removed, and I get error that I'm trying to add index that already exists. But, in test database, which gets recreated anew for every test run and is empty (contains just some seed data), the index is removed.

So, I can't remove PK after creating it unless I recreate index, but I can't add index recreation to migration since it isn't always removed.

I guess something is seriously wrong here, so adding index if it's missing is just a workaround that doesn't fix the actual issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that this *not* be used as the table's primary key.  Simply create an auto-increment field as the PK.  Then, create an index on this pair of fields if you need to use it often to look-up data; a `UNIQUE` index if necessary.

Generally speaking, one of the principles of good database design is that primary keys should not *contain* information:  their only purpose is to unambiguously identify the row.  The PK should have no "meaning" at all.

Comment: This is a good workaround, but doesn't answer why I've been getting these weird errors.